# What are the effects of installing softwares to a removable device?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, storage, sd-card

I am considering purchasing a small (14" screen) laptop which has Windows 10 pre-installed and has an 32GB EMMC storage.

I was thinking that to preserve as much free space on the C: drive (32GB EMMC) that I install any programs *I want on the SD card* (and basically leave only Windows 10 on the C: drive).

**What are the disadvantages installing software to a removable device *(in this case an SD card which I will leave plugged in all the time)* apart from maybe being a bit slower to load?**

Moreover, Windows 10 alone takes around 70% of the 32 GB EMMC storage, and I have to restrict windows updates all the time (except security updates) to prevent C drive from filling up - (any fixes for this as well?)

Comment: Q1. Slower maybe. Hard to say without technical specs. If you can set it to slow removal (I don't have anything to see exact terminology) in Properties it will be faster. Q2. Try typing as admin `cleanmgr /dc`.

Comment: What type of technical specs do you need? Will telling the technical specs of the SD card do? If that is the case, it's a sandisk 128GB class 10 microSDXC card. I wanted to know if this has lesser capacity of data retention than an actual hard disk? And what does that command do? :|

Comment: It is unlikely to make any significant difference. But it's inbuilt drive versus SD card.

Comment: okay, I got that. But will you please tell what ``cleanmgr /dc`` does? - okay just tried that and I was able to clean some 100mb temporary files. Thank you

Comment: What do you think it does?

Comment: I didn't think anything, I just typed ``cleanmgr`` in cmd and hit ``enter``. There popped up a menu, where some of the options were already checked. I just pressed ok and it did rest of the work :)

Comment: You each item you select a help thingy appears in the bottom half.